# python cant open file 'manage.py' - "heroku run python manage.py migrate command input"

Tags: django, heroku, hosting

Hi I have finished my Django pycharm project and I'm now trying to upload it to heroku/ host it on heroku. I have followed this link https://medium.com/@qazi/how-to-deploy-a-django-app-to-heroku-in-2018-the-easy-way-48a528d97f9c which has actually successfully worked for me in the past. When I get to the step were you put this command in however 'heroku run python manage.py migrate' I continue to get this error message 'Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ radiant-retreat-19016... up, run.6371 (Free)
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'
Im not that much of a beginner so I know that my manage.py file is in the right place especially cause I can run ' python manage.py runserver '. I will attach the code to my procFile below along with my manage.py code and settings. I have looked everywhere on the internet for the problem and some people have it but nothing has worked for them. I will attach any other code if you need it. I even transferred all code to a new project and the same problem occurred.

```
web: gunicorn inspect_list2.wsgi






#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'inspect_list2.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()






"""
Django settings for inspect_list project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.14.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'not showing this but its there'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',
    #'auth',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'inspect_list2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'inspect_list2.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.CustomUser'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'front_page'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: Instead of running the heroku command you can set the database credentials in the `settings.py` file and run `python manage.py migrate` that will also work for you?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally figured it out after 10 hours. Other sources online were right. If you refer to the link I posted above at the very bottom command. If you run the git push stuff first than that last command and after that you run the heroku migrate command it should work. WAIT! If it doesn't work then if you have touched your git repository stuff or changed the name or messed with your squilte3 file and you didn't know what you were doing then transfer all your code to another project so the git stuff and squilte3 stuff automatically is made and resets then follow the instruction in this comment again. If not I don't know what to tell you but it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed by this

```
heroku run python **FOLDER**/manage.py migrate
```

ex

```
heroku run python HOME/manage.py migrate
```

Comment: THANK YOU. The older answers all told people to modify their wsgi file and other stuff. This makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Right click manage.py file and look for the option of open in terminal when it does run the code again